# How to customize Amplify Auth Error Messages

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am attempting to implement amplify auth on iOS, and what I would like to be able to do is customize the error message that is displayed to a user when authentication fails, as the default error messages are not end-user friendly, but I have no idea how to do this.

For instance, my signIn method is as follows:

```
func signIn(username: String) {
     
        Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: "bla") { [weak self] result in
        switch result  {
            case .success (let result):
                if case .confirmSignInWithCustomChallenge(_) = result.nextStep {
                    
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.showConfirmationSignInView()
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    print("Sign in succeeded")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print (error)
            
       
            
            }
        }
    }
```

Now in the .failure case, instead of printing the error, I would ideally like to determine if the error is a userNotFound error, or something else. I can't find any info in the docs on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking the `error.code`. for example, for a user who did not confirm the email if he tries to login then `error.code` will have  `UserNotConfirmedException` string value. Amplify auth returns different exception codes for different types of errors. You can see all the exceptions from this [link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/tree/main/packages/amplify_auth_plugin_interface/lib/src/Exceptions). Although it is for flutter, the exception code is identical for any framework. I have used these exception codes in react.